# Show by example that $AB=I$ does not imply that $BA=I$, with $I$ being the identity operator on $Y$. What is a suitable $Y$ for this to hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded linear operators on a normed space $Y$ into $Y$. Show by example that $AB=I$ does not imply that $BA=I$, with $I$ being the identity operator on $Y$

Here is what I have done: Let $z=(z_1,z_2,...)$ be the identity operator on $Y$. Let $A$ and $B$ be the left and right shift, respectively. Then $AB=z$ does not imply $BA=z$.

My question is this: I need to specify an infinite dimensional vector space $Y$, what is a suitable $Y$ for this to hold?

Comment: how about $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ I mean, the shift operator stuff makes it a natural choice.

Comment: Or just $\ell^\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$Y=\ell^{2+}$, i.e. one-sided $\ell^2$, $B$ is the right shift and $A$ is the left shift operators.

Comment: oops, forgot to specify one-sided